# SwiftUI Change ContextMenu Button Color to Red iOS 14

Tags: button, swiftui, contextmenu

Hi is there a way i can do to change the context menu button to red in iOS 14.

I already tried using .destructive. The problem with this, it's only available on iOS 15+.

```
Button(role: .destructive)
```

Also tried using this but it doesn't change the button color at all.

```
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button(action: {
                                    // Delete something
                                }) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                                            .imageScale(.medium)
                                        Text("Delete")
                                    }
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                }
                                

                            }
```

Anyone have work around on implementing this in iOS 14?